# Getting the title of a google calendar event without zend framework

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to find a way to get the title of several all day events that happen once a day only on weekdays in a calendar that I have from a separate URL. I have been working for a while to try and figure out how to just get the Title and the Date for each of the all day events (I think they are all day events.... the ones that appear in the top bar on the normal calendar display).

I tried accessing the xml file for the calendar but I did a control+F and found none of the titles That I know would pop up, so I am not able to parse the xml file (since what I am looking for doesn't exist). I also tried messing around with zend framework and got no luck after a few hours (even with the demos... I blame my web host).

point is, I have no idea what to do now. please help. (just a reminder, all I want to do is READ calendar events)

php is language of choice